# Xcode Countdown for days until Christmas

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode10

I'm looking for a possibility in Xcode to get a label count town the days until Christmas. I tried to count down the days with the NSDate Foundation but didn't achieve a solution :(

This countdown is a present or someone and I appreciate every example code from you!

Thanks in advance!
Benjamin

The code I tried was from a older video but didn´t work out for me... Can someone tell me why and how I can fix it?

Code:

```
import UIKit

class StartViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var dateLabelOutlet: UILabel!

let formatter = DateFormatter()

let userCalendar = NSCalendar.current

let requestedComponents: NSCalendar.Unit = [
    NSCalendar.Unit.Month,
    NSCalendar.Unit.Day,
    NSCalendar.Unit.Hour,
    NSCalendar.Unit.Minute,
    NSCalendar.Unit.Second
]

func printTime(){
    formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss a"
    let startTime = NSDate()
    let endTime = formatter.date(from: "12/24/18 12:00:00 a")

    let timeDifference = userCalendar.dateComponents(requestedComponents, from: startTime, to: endTime!, options: [])     
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you write yourself? It's easier of we can start working with something.

Comment: Xcode is just an IDE, it doesn’t really relate to this. I assume you mean you want to make an iOS app with Swift that does this. Please edit the question and add the code you tried and explain what didn’t work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method calculates and prints the number of days from today until next Christmas

```
func printDays() {
    // create date components of 12/24
    let xmasComponents = DateComponents(month: 12, day: 24)
    // get next occurrence 
    let nextXmas = Calendar.current.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: xmasComponents, matchingPolicy: .strict)!
    // calculate number of days
    let daysUntilXmas = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: Date() , to: nextXmas).day!
    print("Christmas is in \(daysUntilXmas) days")
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked out for me. Really happy to be able to finish the present now soon!

Comment: Can you let me know how I can convert the daysUntilXmas into a var to be able to display it on label?

Comment: `daysUntilXmas` is a constant. The `print` line shows how to display the `Int` value in a string